# How to traverse all Fields in all nested Records in an Avro file and check a certain property in their Types?

Tags: groovy, apache-nifi, avro, debezium

I have an avro file which has records, then in their fields (which have uniontypes) there are other records, which also have fields with union types, and some types have a certain property `connect.name` which i need to check if it equals to `io.debezium.time.NanoTimestamp`. I`m doing this in Apache NiFi using an ExecuteScript processor with Groovy script. 
A shortened example of the Avro schema:

```
{
"type": "record",
"name": "Envelope",
"namespace": "data.none.bpm.pruitsmdb_nautilus_dbo.fast_frequency_tables.avro.test",
"fields": [
    {
        "name": "before",
        "type": [
            "null",
            {
                "type": "record",
                "name": "Value",
                "fields": [
                    {
                        "name": "Id",
                        "type": {
                            "type": "string",
                            "connect.parameters": {
                                "__debezium.source.column.type": "UNIQUEIDENTIFIER",
                                "__debezium.source.column.length": "36"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "CreatedOn",
                        "type": [
                            "null",
                            {
                                "type": "long",
                                "connect.version": 1,
                                "connect.parameters": {
                                    "__debezium.source.column.type": "DATETIME2",
                                    "__debezium.source.column.length": "27",
                                    "__debezium.source.column.scale": "7"
                                },
                                "connect.name": "io.debezium.time.NanoTimestamp"
                            }
                        ],
                        "default": null
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "CreatedById",
                        "type": [
                            "null",
                            {
                                "type": "string",
                                "connect.parameters": {
                                    "__debezium.source.column.type": "UNIQUEIDENTIFIER",
                                    "__debezium.source.column.length": "36"
                                }
                            }
                        ],
                        "default": null
                    }
                ],
                "connect.name": "data.none.bpm.pruitsmdb_nautilus_dbo.fast_frequency_tables.avro.test.Value"
            }
        ],
        "default": null
    },
    {
        "name": "after",
        "type": [
            "null",
            "Value"
        ],
        "default": null
    },
    {
        "name": "source",
        "type": {
            "type": "record",
            "name": "Source",
            "namespace": "io.debezium.connector.sqlserver",
            "fields": [
                {
                    "name": "version",
                    "type": "string"
                },
                {
                    "name": "ts_ms",
                    "type": "long"
                },
                {
                    "name": "snapshot",
                    "type": [
                        {
                            "type": "string",
                            "connect.version": 1,
                            "connect.parameters": {
                                "allowed": "true,last,false"
                            },
                            "connect.default": "false",
                            "connect.name": "io.debezium.data.Enum"
                        },
                        "null"
                    ],
                    "default": "false"
                }
            ],
            "connect.name": "io.debezium.connector.sqlserver.Source"
        }
    },
    {
        "name": "op",
        "type": "string"
    },
    {
        "name": "ts_ms",
        "type": [
            "null",
            "long"
        ],
        "default": null
    }
],
"connect.name": "data.none.bpm.pruitsmdb_nautilus_dbo.fast_frequency_tables.avro.test.Envelope"
```

}

My Groovy code, which obviously seems to be checking the top-level records only, and also I'm not sure whether I'm checking the property `connect.name` correctly:

```
  reader.forEach{ GenericRecord record -> 
    record.getSchema().getFields().forEach{ Schema.Field field ->
      try {
        field.schema().getTypes().forEach{ Schema typeSchema ->
          if(typeSchema.getProp("connect.name") == "io.debezium.time.NanoTimestamp"){
            record.put(field.name(), Long(record.get(field.name()).toString().substring(0, 13)))
            typeSchema.addProp("logicalType", "timestamp-millis")
          }
        }
      } catch(Exception ex){
        println("Catching the exception")
      }
    }
     writer.append(record)
   }
```

My question is - how to traverse all nested Records (there are top-level records' fields which have "record" type and records inside) in the avro file? And when traversing their Fields - how to check correctly that one of their types (which may go in union) has a property `connect.name == io.debezium.time.NanoTimestamp` and if yes, perform a transformation on the field value and add a `logicalType` property to the field`s type?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for a recursion here - there should be a function that will accept the Record as a parameter. When you hit a field that is a nested record then you'll call this function recursively.

Answer (score 1):

Jiri's approach suggestion worked, a recursive function was used, here`s the full code:

```
import org.apache.avro.*
import org.apache.avro.file.*
import org.apache.avro.generic.*

//define input and output files
DataInputStream inputStream = new File('input.avro').newDataInputStream() 
DataOutputStream outputStream = new File('output.avro').newDataOutputStream() 
DataFileStream<GenericRecord> reader = new DataFileStream<>(inputStream, new GenericDatumReader<GenericRecord>())
DataFileWriter<GenericRecord> writer = new DataFileWriter<>(new GenericDatumWriter<GenericRecord>())

def contentSchema = reader.schema //source Avro schema
def records = [] //list will be used to temporary store the processed records

//function which is traversing through all records (including nested ones)
def convertAvroNanosecToMillisec(record){
    record.getSchema().getFields().forEach{ Schema.Field field -> 

        if (record.get(field.name()) instanceof org.apache.avro.generic.GenericData.Record){
            convertAvroNanosecToMillisec(record.get(field.name()))
        }

        if (field.schema().getType().getName() == "union"){
            field.schema().getTypes().forEach{ Schema unionTypeSchema ->
                if(unionTypeSchema.getProp("connect.name") == "io.debezium.time.NanoTimestamp"){
                    record.put(field.name(), Long.valueOf(record.get(field.name()).toString().substring(0, 13)))
                    unionTypeSchema.addProp("logicalType", "timestamp-millis")
                }
            }
        } else {
            if(field.schema().getProp("connect.name") == "io.debezium.time.NanoTimestamp"){
                record.put(field.name(), Long.valueOf(record.get(field.name()).toString().substring(0, 13)))
                field.schema().addProp("logicalType", "timestamp-millis")
            }
        }

    } 

    return record
}

//reading all records from incoming file and adding to the temporary list
reader.forEach{ GenericRecord contentRecord -> 
    records.add(convertAvroNanosecToMillisec(contentRecord))
}

//creating a file writer object with adjusted schema
writer.create(contentSchema, outputStream)

//adding records to the output file from the temporary list and closing the writer
records.forEach{ GenericRecord contentRecord -> 
    writer.append(contentRecord)
}

writer.close()
```